# Process a Bunch of Different Input Strings (QueryString)

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I have a webpage that is a Search page.  There are a few pre-defined searches that need to be in place.  The method I have taken to handle this, along with normal searches, is to have the QueryString force the search.  There is a search querystring, currently about 10 or so different "searches".

I then have a ProcessSearch method with a switch it in the setup and perform each search:

```
    switch (QueryString)
    {
        case "person":
            SearchPerson();
            break;

        case "firstname":
            firstNameText = inputtedValue;
            SearchPerson();
            break;
        .
        .
        .
    }
```

You get the idea, I hope.  Is there a better way to do this.  Just seems like I might be missing a simplier, easier to read solution.

**One last edit:**

Does making the strings Enums buy me anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a solid, readable solution to your problem.  There *are* other ways to do it but I think what you have is fine.

Comment: What are the other ways?  Just curious.

Comment: Switch statements like this can often be refactored into a Dictionary<String,Delegate> if there are many of them. Without knowing more of your application it is difficult to say if this would be a good idea :)